# Adding TemplateField to DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, detailsview, templatefield

How do I add TemplateField control to the beginning of the DetailsView Fields collection?

Here is my code..

```
TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();
...
...
dv.Fields.Add(tf);
```

This adds to the very end of the DetailsView control. I tried dv.Fields(0) but there is no Add method available. I noticed that we have dv.Fields.RemoveAt but we do not have dv.Fields.AddAt...

Any ideas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Add the field at the beginning, use the **[INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfieldcollection.insert.aspx)** method as follows:

```
TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();
...
...
dv.Fields.Insert(0, tf);
```